# Fetching complex objects by raw SQL query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-4.3

I would like to fetch from database complex object using single query. Let's look at the following example:

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableA.B_Id = TableB.Id
```

and corresponding classes:

```
public class QueryResult
{
    public TableA A { get; set; }
    public TableB B { get; set; }
}

public class TableA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeContentA { get; set; }
    public int B_Id { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SomeContentB { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to execute the raw SQL query from above against the database and get collection of QueryResult objects with correctly set A and B properties. So far I tried using SqlQuery method, but I only managed to get collection of QueryResult objects with nulls in A and B properties (apparently returned result set was not correctly binded to properties):

```
var results = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<QueryResult>(\\example_query).ToList();
```

Note that:

- I shouldn't list manually columns in SELECT statement. TableA and TableB classes and SQL tables are likely to change over time, but those changes will be consistent.
- Three queries (one to fetch IDs from TableA and TableB, second to fetch objects from TableA, third for objects from TableB) will hurt performance and I should try avoid it if possible.

I am using Entity Framework 4.3 and SQL Server 2012.

Thanks,
Art

Comment: is the `B_Id` an actual foreign key here?  If so, is there a reason you aren't referencing a `TableB` in your `TableA` so you can just load it through EF, rather than using raw SQL?

Comment: No, it is not, I just added it to the example to use a join. Sorry for the confusion. In the actual problem there is no relation between TableA and TableB and there is no option to replace the code with regular EF constructions.

Comment: Is there a reason for using EF4.x?  Thought about upgrading to 6.x?  Also, do you have access to create a SProc in the DB to perform the complex joining?

Comment: Shouldn't your sql be:
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.B_Id = TableB.Id

Answer (score 0):

You can still use regular EF constructions by just mapping your classes to their corresponding tables and forcing the join in LINQ-To-Entities:

```
using(var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    return ctx.TableA
         .Join(ctx.TableB, a=>a.B_Id, b=>b.Id, (a,b)=>
              new QueryResult{TableA=a, TableB=b});
}
```

I think that's the only way, at least up to EF6.