# Returning multiple related entity types from raw SQL queries in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Noodling around with raw SQL Queries in Entity Framework. Am I right in thinking that given these two related EF classes:

```
public partial class Campaign
{
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}

public partial class Quote
{
    public int QuoteId { get; set; }
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }

    public virtual Campaign Campaign { get; set; }
}
```

The tables are joined by a foreign key, and the objects were generated by DB first entity framework.

I can't issue a raw query that will get all the campaigns and their related quotes? I've tried this:

```
string sqlQuery = "select * from Campaign c join Quote q on q.CampaignId = c.CampaignId";
var meh = Entities.Database.SqlQuery<Campaign>(sqlQuery);
```

Which just brings back the Campaigns without Quotes. So I'm guessing it's not feasible but I just wanted to check I'm not doing something wrong?

I couldn't find a definitive answer in the documentation. And this older related question [Fetching complex objects by raw SQL query in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180826/fetching-complex-objects-by-raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework) has upvotes but no answers.

People have suggested this is a duplicate of [EF5 db.Database.SqlQuery mapping returned objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359522/ef5-db-database-sqlquery-mapping-returned-objects) but there's one difference: I need related, nested entities rather than a complex type. Effectively, I want to use SqlQuery to return an identical result set to

```
Entities.Campaigns.Include(c => c.Quotes);
```

(If you want to know why it's because I have a much more complex set of Includes which is returning large amounts of unasked for data. No-one seems to be able to explain why this is happening, so I'm casting round for alternative approaches)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF5 db.Database.SqlQuery mapping returned objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359522/ef5-db-database-sqlquery-mapping-returned-objects)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359522/ef5-db-database-sqlquery-mapping-returned-objects

Comment: @dotctor This is the best answer.  He is trying to make the EF work like a database and is understandably having a hard time.  It is designed for Code First, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do this with raw SQL query. You are trying to achieve nested realtionship model which EF provides with all the model mappings with raw sql query which obviously will provide the same flat result as you get by running sql query on database. You are killing Entity framework relational modeling concept and want to get the same result which EF provides with its relational mapping mechanism